# How to target .style attribut with .querySelectorAll selector?

Tags: javascript, css, selectors-api

I have selected a specific class via `.querySelectorAll`:

```
var hit3 = document.querySelectorAll(".lattern.hit-3 .circle");
```

I am now trying to target and adjust a `.style.visibility` attribut on this element, by doing the following:

```
hit3.style.visibility = "visible";
```

This however results in an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined
```

How do I target a specific `.style` with the above `.querySelectorAll` selector?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muqfawzs/1/)

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist... so you need to iterate over it

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` returns an array like structure(NodeList) which does not have the `style` attribute.

But I think what you need is slightly different, I assume want to display the circle for the clicked element then

```js
var latternElement = document.querySelectorAll('.lattern');

function toggleElement(el) {
  el.querySelector('.circle').classList.add('visible'); //also minor tweaks, use css rules
}

for (var i = 0; i < latternElement.length; i++) {
  latternElement[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (this.classList.contains("hit-3")) { //minor tweaks - only supported in modern browsers
      toggleElement(this);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.lattern {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: green;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.circle.default,
.circle.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="lattern hit-1">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="lattern hit-2">
  <div class="circle default"></div>
</div>
<div class="lattern hit-3">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` return a node list so you should specify the index of element you want to change :

```
hit3[0].style.visibility = "visible";
```

If you want to change the css of all the elements returned you should loop through them, see [Johny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601756/how-to-target-style-attribut-with-queryselectorall-selector/35601811#answer-35601817).

Hope this helps.